# Truncate string to fit CGSize?

Tags: ios, string, swift

I am trying to have string truncate if the actual width of the string exceeds a certain size (not to number of characters in string!)

I can get the width of the string using `NSString.sizeWithAttributes`

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
label.text = "Testing text"
let labelStringSize = (label.text! as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: label.font]) 
// labelStringSize dimensions: w 89.267 h 20.287
```

But how would I handle truncating the label's text if, say, labelStringSize exceeded 50?

Is there an easier way to to do this I have overlooked?

Comment: The _label_ truncates the text _for_ you.

Comment: @matt perhaps he doesn't want the "..." that a label normally adds when it truncates a string? Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Then he can just not wrap. But until he specifies why having the label do the truncation is no good to him, there's no point speculating. It is utterly unclear what he _really_ wants to do.